# VirtualBox import error Cannot register the DVD image

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running v 4.2.6.
Starting this morning, I can't import some VMs, and some of my existing VMs are showing up as inaccessible and have the following error showing in the UI,

The same error too when i took the vm to another PC and try to open it with virtual box (v 5.0.10):

> Cannot register the DVD image
>
> 'C:\Program
> Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso'
> {f5022f2e-0adc-4767-879d-65058a5578c5} because a CD/DVD image
>
> 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' with UUID
> {fc087cbc-df04-47b4-b42f-25f614463f78} already exists. Result Code:
> E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057) Component:  VirtualBox Interface:
> IVirtualBox {3b2f08eb-b810-4715-bee0-bb06b9880ad2}

Comment: please feedback is it not the place to put this question in `stackoverflow` or there is another place fits more

Comment: This probably belongs over on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I solved it by open the file `win 7 64.vbox` with text editor and remove the tag:

```
<DVDImages>
   <Image uuid="{fd686a98-c1a6-42d9-82aa-67728b524d53}" location="C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso"/>
</DVDImages>
```

Know that by removing the tag it will be added as empty tag.
and reopent the vm of virtual box again. and it worked

Answer (score 33):

Open the .VBOX file in any text editor of your choice.
find the following lines:

```
[...]
<DVDImages>
        <Image uuid="{b058bc48-c451-4cff-9db0-d01c70e99c28}"
location="/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso"/>

[...]
```

Delete all entries between  and  section. After deleting the contents, your .VBOX file will look like below.

```
<DVDImages>
</DVDImages>
```

Save and close the file.

That’s it. Now, you can load the virtual machine without any issues.

Comment: https://www.ostechnix.com/virtualbox-error-cannot-register-the-dvd-image-because-uuid-already-exists/

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 virtual machines XP-x86 and Win7-x64 and precisely removing tag image uuid the issue got fixed and was able to add the new pre-created VM.

Comment: How is this different from the existing answer?

Answer (score 0):

It is because there is a conflict with the existing inserted media. Ejecting the existing drive via Virtual Media Manager might solve it.

Ref: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=51911

Answer (score 0):

For me none of these answers worked for me.
I needed to delete the same lines that are mentioned above. but from `C:\Users\USER\\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox`.

In my case it was referencing paths that didn't exist.